# Increase chances of name being picked from Array

Tags: c#, arrays, console

For my program, I've prompted the user to put 20 names into an array (the array size is 5 for testing for now), this array is then sent to a text document. I need to make it so that it will randomly pick a name from the list and display it (which I have done). But I now need to make it increase the chances of a name being picked, how would I go about doing this?

Eg. I want to increase the chances of the name 'Jim' being picked from the array.

```
class Programt
{
    static void readFile()
    {
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string winner;
        string file = @"C:\names.txt";
        string[] classNames = new string[5];
        Random RandString = new Random();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Names in the text document are: ");
            foreach (var displayFile in File.ReadAllLines(file))
            Console.WriteLine(displayFile);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 names:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                classNames[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            File.Create(file).Close();
            File.WriteAllLines(file, classNames);
            Console.WriteLine("Writing names to file...");
            winner = classNames[RandString.Next(0, classNames.Length)];
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe winner of the randomiser is: {0} Congratulations! ", winner);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.Write("Completed");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to append the selected name to your text file so there are more entries of it

Comment: Increase the chances of *which* name?

Comment: Of a certain name typed in, in this case 'Jim'.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways of doing this. You can either produce a RNG with a normal distribution targeting one number.

Or the simpler way is a translational step. Generate in the range 0-100 and then produce code which translates to the answer in a biased way e.g.

- 0-5 : Answer 1
- 6-10: Answer 2
- 11-90: Answer 3
- 91-95: Answer 4
- 96-100:  Answer 5

This gives an 80% chance of picking Answer 3, the others only get a 5% chance

So where you currently have `RandString.Next(0, classNames.Length)` you can replace that with a function something like `GetBiasedIndex(0, classNames.Length, 3)`

The function would look something like this (with test code):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int[] results = new int[5];

        Random RandString = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var output = GetBiasedIndex(RandString, 0, 4, 3);
            results[output]++;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(results[i].ToString());
        }
        label1.Text = builder.ToString();
    }


    private int GetBiasedIndex(Random rng, int start, int end, int target)
    {
        //Number between 0 and 100 (Helps to think percentage)
        var check = rng.Next(0, 100);
        //There's a few ways to do this next bit, but I'll try to keep it simple
        //Allocate x% to the target and split the remaining y% among all the others
        int x = 80;//80% chance of target
        int remaining = 100 - x;//20% chance of something else
        //Take the check for the target out of the last x% (we can take it out of any x% chunk but this makes it simpler
        if (check > (100 - x))
        {
            return target;
        }
        else
        {
            //20% left if there's 4 names remaining that's 5% each
            var perOther = (100 - x) / ((end - start) - 1);
            //result is now in the range 0..4
            var result = check / perOther;
            //avoid hitting the target in this section
            if (result >= target)
            {
                //adjust the index we are returning since we have already accounted for the target
                result++;
            }
            //return the index;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and the output:

> 52
>   68
>   55
>   786
>   39

If you're going to call this function repeatedly you'll need to pass in the instance of the RNG so that you don't reset the seed each call.

If you want to target a name instead of an index you just need to look up that name first and have an else condition for when that name isn't found

Comment: Would you be able to explain further detail on the range 0-100? I'm unsure on how that works in code.